# Accessing variables from other class - If-Statment does not work

Tags: java, if-statement

I have two classes, both "scanning" a name and a password from the user. When I try to check if they are correct, my if-statement always returns "false".

```
public class User{
   Scanner scan = new S...
   String username, pw;

   public void regis(){
      username = scan.nextLine();
      pw = scan.nextLine();
   }
   public String getUsername(){
      return username;
   }
   //same for getPw()..
}

public class Check{
   Scanner scan2 = new ...;
   User usr = new User();

   public void check(){
      String name, pass;
      System.out.print("name?");
      name = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.print("password?");
      pass = scan.nextLine();

      if(name.equals(usr.getUsername()) && pass.equals(usr.getPw())){
         return true;
      }else{
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

I always get "false" as result. I tried to set `username` and `pw` from `class User` to *static* and it worked. Why is my solution not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As @ScaryWombat pointed out, you need to initialize **usr** by calling `User usr = new User();` and perform the `.regis();` method. This works --> [Check out my Gist link](https://gist.github.com/sometowngeek/b76ee3ca7a1091523a69669405d0e6e7)

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the method on `User`

```
User usr = new User();
```

then you need to call to get the values to fill `username` and `pw`

```
usr.regis ();
```